# Which HTML 5 Standard supports reading data from USB connected device currently we are managing with ActiveX and Java Applet

Tags: html, applet, activex

We have healthcare device data reading functionality implemented in Browser application for specific client need - ActiveX for IE and Java Applet for other two major browsers Chrome and Firefox

1. ActiveX - Microsoft already announced ending support to their own creation with Edge , their new browser
2. Java Applet - most of the Browser vendors announced their support to NPAPI. Chrome already ended support on SEP 2015 and Firefox ending support by end of 2016

In view of no support for both the technologies, we are left with no other option but to explore / look for if HTML 5 Standard can support this need.

If anyone can provide more information on HTML 5 standard would be of great help.

Note:- at least for now Desktop option is rules out by clients , so any HTML 5 is the only alternative for us.

Comment: Its been long I revisited my question and thought of updating in case someone still looking for this to work out. Here is what I would do if something like this needs to be developed today:

- [webassembly](https://webassembly.org/)

Comment: Basically TWO options - 
- [webassembly](https://webassembly.org/) - cross browser cross platform and
- [blazer](https://blazor.net/) - cross browser to deliver but more for MS dev stack

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's released yet, but [WebUSB](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebAPI/WebUSB) is probably what you're looking for.

In the mean time you can use [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) to provide that support on most browsers which don't support NPAPI/ActiveX (and FireFox plans to add support for Native Messaging).  I don't know of a solution for MS Edge and similar.